# Symfony2 - How can I simplify this querybuilder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a working queryBuilder that gets posts by category and excludes the one being shown and sets a max limit.

Question: How can I simplify this queryBuilder?

In the query, I am pretty sure I don't need to join the 2 tables (category/post connected with a OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship) and am setting $category in the controller, is there a better way of refactoring this?

**queryBuilder**

```
public function getRelatedPosts($exceptPost, $limit, $category)
{
return $this
->createQueryBuilder('post') 
->leftJoin('post.category','category') 
->where('post != :exceptPost') 
->setParameter('exceptPost', $exceptPost) 
->andWhere('category = :category') 
->setParameter('category', $category) 
->orderBy('post.createdAt', 'DESC') 
->setMaxResults($limit)
->getQuery()
->execute();
}
```

**controller**

```
public function showAction($slug)
{
    $post = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')
        ->findOneBy(array(
            'slug' => $slug
        ));

    if (null === $post) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Post was not found');
    }

    $category = $post->getCategory(); 

    $posts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')
        ->getRelatedPosts($post, 4, $category);

    return array(
        'post'  => $post,
        'posts' => $posts
   );
}
```

**updated queryBuilder**

```
public function getRelatedPosts($exceptPost, $limit, $category)
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('post')
        ->where('post != :exceptPost')
        ->andWhere('post.category = :category')
        ->setParameter('exceptPost', $exceptPost)
        ->setParameter('category', $category)
        ->orderBy('post.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults($limit)

        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the join and change the where clause of your query for *category* to `->andWhere('post.category = :category')` then set the parameter as `->setParameter('category', $category->getId())`? If the referenced column name is `id`

Comment: I've updated my working query above. And removed the join, is there any way I can get rid of having to set the category in the controller? `category = $post->getCategory();` and passing it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but you may want something like this:
**Controller**

```
public function showAction($slug)
{
   $post = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')
      ->findOneBy(array(
        'slug' => $slug
   ));

   if (null === $post) {
      throw $this->createNotFoundException('Post was not found');
   }

   $posts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')
      ->getRelatedPosts($post, 4);

   return array(
      'post'  => $post,
      'posts' => $posts
   );
}
```

**Repository**

```
public function getRelatedPosts($exceptPost, $limit)
{
   return $this
     ->createQueryBuilder('post')
     ->where('post.id != :exceptPost')
     ->andWhere('post.category = :category')
     ->setParameter('exceptPost', $exceptPost->getId())
     ->setParameter('category', $exceptPost->getCategory()->getId())
     ->orderBy('post.createdAt', 'DESC')
     ->setMaxResults($limit)
     ->getQuery()
     ->getResult();
}
```

*You can also build this in a join query of post table with itself or SELECT ... IN (...); if you are interested*